# Hidding/showing properties from UNDO panel depending on certain property value?

Tags: properties, operator

I have an operator with some different properties (mostly bools).

When a certain property is true, it makes no sense to show the others (they are related to a different "part of the execution" when the other prperty is False).

So, for the ease of use, **I would like to hide the unnecessary properties.**

Is it possible? (I know about the `HIDDEN` flag in the definition, but not sure if its possible to change it dynamically (nor how is made, in case its possible)

Comment: Damn, just found it right after asking ._. Is it possible to add a draw() function to an operator to customize how is drawed in the undo pannel.